# Redirecting with 404 doesnt work

Tags: php

I havea code that should redirect in case it doesnt have some request parameter set correctly.

```
          if(!is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
                         header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
                    header('Location: '.$url);
                    exit();
               }
```

Problem is that whenever I check with Firefoxes plugin, live HTTP headers, I see 302 temporary redirect. why is that? why no 404 response is given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem is that whenever I check with Firefoxes plugin, live HTTP
>   headers, I see 302 temporary redirect. why is that? why no 404
>   response is given?

**Not sure what you want to do here** but following will provide your purpose.

```
if (! is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $url, true, 404);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: it didnt do the redirect.. it just threw 404..why

Comment: You can have redirect (status code 302) or not found (status code 404) but not both.

Comment: hmmm.. so what you are saying is that i do a 302 redirect.. although.....may be i could simply redirect and then throw 404 with htaccess.. but i dont think it would work

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make sense to send a `Location` header with a `404` status code.

`Location` means "What you asked for is over here"

`404` means "I don't have what you asked for"

The two statements are incompatible.

If you want to send a particular human readable explanation of the error, then just output it as you would for any other kind of document. You could `include()` it if you like. Don't try to redirect to it.

Comment: if i use location it gives me 302 status code.. so i need to combine it with 404. I know i could use an include..thats what i use.. what i want is to produce a status code. And at the same time change the url perhaps

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd — How is it that something is both not found and somewhere else at the same time?

Comment: When I change a location.. the new url is obtained by the server and goes through htaccess. In the htaccess it goes to another redirect 302 , to go to the destination page. Thats why when I deliver the header set as 404 the first time, when the htaccess gets involved it overrides the the 404 header redirect with its own 302 redirect. Thats why I end up with a 302 redirect instead of 404 redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can only send ONE of the headers you are attempting as stated above.

In case of 404 - this will display the error relevant error pages as defined by you're web server config.

To do what you want... you will need to modify the server's 404 from a plain html to a php page and work out what to display from there (you can base on referrer etc).

From within the 'dynamic' 404 page, you can then do you're redirect if required.

Comment: You can send as many headers as you like. It just doesn't make sense to send a 404 with a Location.

Comment: sorry yes... I that's what I mean :)

Comment: hmm.. and then put this in the htaccess perhaps: ErrorDocument 404 /errormessages/404.php

Comment: Yup... then you can make 404.php process it... $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] 'should' contain the URL you likewise $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] should contain any url params, so you can then use that info to process the 404 request as you see fit.